# Swfobject + IE 9 height 100% issue

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-9, fullscreen

I have two example pages.

1. http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/testsuite_2_2/test_dynamic_fullbrowserflash.html
   this displays 100% width and height flash without a problem across all the browsers including IE9.
2. http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/testsuite_2_2/test_dynamic_fullbrowserflash_adv.html
   this displays 100% width and height with min-height and min-width without a problem across all the browsers except for the IE9.

I need #2 link work with IE9. (fullsized flash with min-height and min-width)

I've tried everything I can do, but can't find a single clue...

Any advise will be appreciated..

Comment: Hi both works fine on my Win 7 64 IE9 32Bit.

Comment: don't you see like..3px bottom in IE9?

Comment: @pstar // the second one doesn't even render as 100% height in my IE9;

Comment: just found http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2010/10/ie9s_viewport_code_is_broken.html article.

Comment: is this fixed in the release version

Answer (score 3):

Spent quite some time looking for the solution and the only one that seemed to work for me without making any major changes is the one that I found here

http://code.google.com/p/swffit/issues/detail?id=16

Basically, I added the following lines as suggested by the last poster in the link above

```
<style type="text/css">
    // This line of code makes the flash appear full-sized in other browsers (Chrome, FireFox, etc) 
    html { height:100%; }           

    // These lines of code make the flash appear full-sized specifically for IE   
    object{
        position: absolute;
        outline: none;
    }
</style>
```

It's a hack but it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/issues/detail?id=552

this link say:

> The source of the problem is IE9 standards mode no longer returns
>   functions as object type. typeof function(){} == "function" returns
>   true in IE9 standards mode, instead of "object"
>
> Therefore, swfobject.js on line 564
>   needs to be changed to check that styleSheet.addRule() now returns
>   "function" in standards mode.

And this is the llink to the new swobject working in IE9

https://github.com/swfobject

:)

Comment: Instead of just linking to the answer it would be better to summarize the information contained in the link here as well. Also, explain what you did to make the new object. 

This way, when the link is no longer working people can still use your SO answer to solve their problems.

Comment: ok, but I hope the google code link does not die, that would mean that the project of swfObjec no longer exists and it is better to use something else more effective.

Comment: It might change. Though I accept that the guideline is a general one, it is still better to use it :).